# Nested formula escape - Document.write

Tags: javascript, nested, document

I'm trying to do the below but can't escape the nested forumala

Used character variants and escapes

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>" + document.referrer.split('?')[1]+"'" +document.referrer.split('?')[2]+"#" +document.referrer.split('?')[3] + \"'" + "https://www.example.com'" + "<\/script>"); </script>
```

Stuck on `\"'"`

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do, and give a concrete example of an input and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing this message in the JavaScript console?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

If so, I'm pretty sure you just need to put the \ character inside the double-quotes, and escape it properly, like so:

```
"\\'"
```

Here is the full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>" + document.referrer.split('?')[1] + "'" + document.referrer.split('?')[2] + "#" + document.referrer.split('?')[3] + "\\'" + "https://www.example.com'" + "<\/script>");</script>
```